# Missing something in connection info String using dblink

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

What I am trying to do is to connect 2 databases and move the data from one db to another via dblink. Here is what I did:

1. I created a dblink extension

   - 1.1. I created a postgres_fdw extension
2. I verified if my dblink works (see code)
3. I testted the connection of the databse
4. I created a foreign data wrapper
5. I created a server with connection details 
   5.1 I mapped the server with the user
6. I tested the created server (error message - my main issue!)
7. I gave the required permission to map user
8. Select query

I have been googling my issue for two days now and could not find anything that may help me.

`SELECT dblink_connect('host=localhost user=postgres password=mypw dbname=nameofthedb')`

`create foreign data wrapper fdw validator postgresql_fdw_validator;`

`Create Server Ahmed FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER FDW OPTIONS (hostaddr '127.0.0.1',dbname 'nameofthedb');`

`CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres server Ahmed OPTIONS (user 'postgres', password 'mypw');`

`select dblink_connect('Ahmed') -- NOT WORKING

GRANT USAGE ON FOREIGN SERVER Ahmed TO postgres*/`

`select * from dblink
('Ahmed', 'select id from nameofthedb.public.pois') --not working
AS DATA(id INTEGER);`

Here is the error I get:

**ERROR:**  could not establish connection

**DETAIL:**  missing "=" after "Ahmed" in connection info string

SQL state: 08001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case sensitivity problem.

SQL is case insensitive, so PostgreSQL converts all SQL except string constants and identifiers in double quotes to lower case.

As a consequence, the foreign server is really called `ahmed`.

The first argument in the `dblink` call is the string literal `'Ahmed'`, which is *not* converted to lower case.

So `dblink` first looks for a named connection `Ahmed`, doesn't find it, then it looks for a foreign server `Ahmed`, *again doesn't find it* and finally resorts to interpreting it as a connection string, which causes the error message.

**Solution:** Use only lower case names.